# How to adding design in project on Xamarin IOS C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have project coding on Xamarin iOS(С#) and design
rendered in Xamarin designer on file "Main.storiboard".
My project have design for iphone 5s, how add my design on iphone 6?

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use Autolayout to make a uniform design?

Comment: where I can set autolayout? @iamIcarus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autolayout may seem easy but there is alot of tweaking to get the desired uniform layout (Quick tutorial on the link below)

> http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2

Try this:

1. Open your storyboard with XCode
2. Find and select the UI Item you want to set constrains with autolayout
3. Click the Pin button at the lower right corner of XCode (see picture below)
4. Add your own constrains in the popup window and press the "Add Constrains" button to add them

[image: C]